# Mongoose fetch records from two related collections with populate

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I need to know how to perform lookup operation in the following collections.
The id of collection one is used as projectsId in collection two. I have given the `contoller.js` and model files below kindly tell me where I have to place the lookup to get the records from two collections

collection one:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58dcda850a13352724d4c716"),
    "name" : "senthil",
    "designation" : "CI",
    "berief_text" : null,
    "status" : 1,
    "__v" : 0,
    "type" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58dcdade0a13352724d4c719"),
    "name" : "ssss",
    "designation" : "sssss",
    "berief_text" : null,
    "status" : 2,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

collection two:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58dcda850a13352724d4c717"),
    "imageLocation" : "uploads\\project_images\\14908688692032.png",
    "projectId" : ObjectId("58dcda850a13352724d4c716"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58dcda850a13352724d4c718"),
    "imageLocation" : "uploads\\project_images\\1490868869210201876891658ad792131c9520170222051225.JPG",
    "projectId" : ObjectId("58dcda850a13352724d4c716"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58dcdade0a13352724d4c71a"),
    "imageLocation" : "uploads\\project_images\\14908689587042.png",
    "projectId" : ObjectId("58dcdade0a13352724d4c719"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58dcdade0a13352724d4c71b"),
    "imageLocation" : "uploads\\project_images\\14908689587321.png",
    "projectId" : ObjectId("58dcdade0a13352724d4c719"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

controller.js

```
var express = require("express"),
 router = express.Router(),
 project = require("../../models/project.js"),
 projectimage = require("../../models/projectimages.js"),
router.get("/", function(req, res) {



 project.find({}, function(err, data){
          if(err){
            res.send(err);
          }
          res.send(data);
        });

  projectimage.find({}, function(err, data){
          if(err){
            res.send(err);
          }
          res.send(data);
        });


})
```

project.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
 Schema = mongoose.Schema,
 objectId = mongoose.Schema.ObjectId;
    var projectSchema = new Schema({
      name    : {type: String, required : true},
      designation    : {type: String, required : true},
      status    : {type: Number, required : true},
      type    : {type: Number, required : true},
      berief_text : {type: String, required : true},
        }); 
    var project = mongoose.model("project", projectSchema);
    module.exports = project;
```

projectimages.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
 Schema = mongoose.Schema,
 objectId = mongoose.Schema.ObjectId;

var ProjectimageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    imageLocation: String,
    projectId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'project'
    },

});

var projectimage = mongoose.model("projectimage", ProjectimageSchema);

module.exports = projectimage;
```

obtained output

Server is running at : http://localhost:3002

```
[ { _id: 58dcda850a13352724d4c716,
    name: 'senthil',
    designation: 'CI',
    berief_text: null,
    status: 1,
    __v: 0,
    type: 1 },
  { _id: 58dcdade0a13352724d4c719,
    name: 'ssss',
    designation: 'sssss',
    berief_text: null,
    status: 2,
    __v: 0 } ]
[ { _id: 58dcda850a13352724d4c717,
    imageLocation: 'uploads\\project_images\\14908688692032.png',
    projectId: 58dcda850a13352724d4c716,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 58dcda850a13352724d4c718,
    imageLocation: 'uploads\\project_images\\1490868869210201876891658ad792131c9520170222051225.JPG',
    projectId: 58dcda850a13352724d4c716,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 58dcdade0a13352724d4c71a,
    imageLocation: 'uploads\\project_images\\14908689587042.png',
    projectId: 58dcdade0a13352724d4c719,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 58dcdade0a13352724d4c71b,
    imageLocation: 'uploads\\project_images\\14908689587321.png',
    projectId: 58dcdade0a13352724d4c719,
    __v: 0 } ]
[ { _id: 58dcda850a13352724d4c716,
    name: 'senthil',
    designation: 'CI',
    berief_text: null,
    status: 1,
    __v: 0,
    type: 1 },
  { _id: 58dcdade0a13352724d4c719,
    name: 'ssss',
    designation: 'sssss',
    berief_text: null,
    status: 2,
    __v: 0 } ]
[ { _id: 58dcda850a13352724d4c717,
    imageLocation: 'uploads\\project_images\\14908688692032.png',
    projectId: 58dcda850a13352724d4c716,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 58dcda850a13352724d4c718,
    imageLocation: 'uploads\\project_images\\1490868869210201876891658ad792131c9520170222051225.JPG',
    projectId: 58dcda850a13352724d4c716,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 58dcdade0a13352724d4c71a,
    imageLocation: 'uploads\\project_images\\14908689587042.png',
    projectId: 58dcdade0a13352724d4c719,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 58dcdade0a13352724d4c71b,
    imageLocation: 'uploads\\project_images\\14908689587321.png',
    projectId: 58dcdade0a13352724d4c719,
    __v: 0 } ]
```

expected output

```
[ { _id: 58dcda850a13352724d4c716,
    name: 'senthil',
    designation: 'CI',
    berief_text: null,
    status: 1,
    __v: 0,
    type: 1.
    images:[{ _id: 58dcda850a13352724d4c717,
    imageLocation: 'uploads\\project_images\\14908688692032.png',
    projectId: 58dcda850a13352724d4c716,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 58dcda850a13352724d4c718,
    imageLocation: 'uploads\\project_images\\1490868869210201876891658ad792131c9520170222051225.JPG',
    projectId: 58dcda850a13352724d4c716,
    __v: 0 }] 
},

]
```

my for each loop

```
 project.find({}, function(err, data){
          if(err){
            res.send(err);
          }

for each (var v in data) {
    console.log(v);
}
        });
```

Comment: You asked 25 questions and you did not mark one right answer?

Comment: Your question phrasing is little confusing! Let me understand what you are trying to do. Do you want `projectId` in `ProjectimageSchema` to be populated by actual `project` object?

Comment: yes i need the records from both the collections

Comment: i have up voted instead  of marking right @lin

Comment: @vimalkumar great, now try to check your questions an mark right answers, so other users can get a benefit from it. Its also how stackoverflow works. Thx =)

Comment: ok will do that @lin

Comment: @vimalkumar thx m8. This will help you to get help in the future. Some users check for this before helping ;)

Comment: thank you will continue it in future @lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to to get referenced data. While your reference is currently be defined in your `ProjectimageSchema` you have to add a ref to `projectsSchema` too. You may going to rename the ref property `projectId` in your `ProjectimageSchema` into `project` to make it more clear.

#### Project Schema

```
var projectSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required : true},
    designation: {type: String, required : true},
    status: {type: Number, required : true},
    type: {type: Number, required : true},
    berief_text: {type: String, required : true},
    images: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Projectimage'
    }
});
```

#### ProjectImages Schema

```
var ProjectimageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    imageLocation: String,
    project: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'project'
    }
});
```

Once you done this you could fetch the related data + related data with populate:

```
//get all project with relates images
project.find()
    .populate('images')
    .exec(function (err, post) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
    });

//get all project images with relates projects
projectimage.find()
    .populate('project')
    .exec(function (err, post) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
    });
```

Comment: I have tried it and i have posted the output it is ok but i need output like expected output

Comment: Whats wrong with the output? It does looks like all the data you need.

Comment: nothing wrong it was really help full but  while displaying the project details the  output  format should be similar to   expected output

Comment: Yea ok, but what is your expected output?

Comment: Well m8, you fetched the data you need by using my answer. Are you not able to create a `for` or a `forEach` loop by yourself ?

Comment: yeah buddy am trying foreach loop will make it

Comment: @vimalkumar Glad to help ya ;) don't forget to mark the right answer :P :P :P

Comment: Glad to help ya =)

Comment: one more help buddy will you check my for each loop syntax i have posted above am not getting it

Comment: what is `for each` :D .... https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach please google that kind of stuff. I think you should be able to create a loop with the help of google yourself.

Comment: `for each` is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in